# Consulta de fecha sobre BD Access

Tags: vb.net, date, ms-access

Información previa: Tengo una base de datos con un campo tipo Fecha/Hora en Access (dd/mm/aa hh:mm:ss). La idea es meter una fecha (introducida en tres TextBox `TBDia` `TBMes` `TBAnio` ) y que me saque los registros de esa fecha (para ver las horas) en un `DataGridView` llamado `DGVFechas` . Este es mi código:

```
    'cogemos la fecha de los TextBox'
    Dim fecha As Date = DateSerial(TBAnio.Text, TBMes.Text, TBDia.Text)

    'cogemos todos los datos de la fecha'
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source=F:\CrossChex.mdb")
    con.Open()
    Dim query2 As String = "SELECT CheckTime, CheckType FROM Checkinout WHERE CheckTime = " & fecha
    Dim DA2 As New OleDbDataAdapter(query2, con)
    Dim DT2 As New DataTable
    DA2.Fill(DT2)

    DGVFechas.DataSource = DT2

    'cambiamos el nombre de las columnas del DataGridView'
    DGVFechas.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Horas"
```

He probado declarando `fecha` como `string` y no he sido capaz de hacerlo funcionar tampoco. Supongo que el fallo está en la consulta, que no será "=" sino "LIKE" o similar, pero ya he probado todas las combinaciones que se me han ocurrido y no he encontrado la forma.

Hay fragmentos de código que he suprimido ya que no son importantes para este fallo, quizá he quitado algo de más pero creo que no es el caso.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este tipo de problemas suelen tener un origen común: **no se debe nunca concatenar cadenas para generar queries**. Por un lado, expones la aplicación a Sql Injection. Por otro, a veces aparecen problemas como este.

Aunque no lo dices explicitamente, entiendo que `CheckTime` es de tipo `DateTime`, pero tu le pasas una cadena para que trate de compararlo. La mejor solución es usar siempre consultas parametrizadas. De esa manera la conversión de tipos y generación del query la hace el motor de base de datos.

En tu caso, puedes probar de la siguiente manera:

```
Dim query2 As String = "SELECT CheckTime, CheckType FROM Checkinout WHERE CheckTime = @fecha"
Dim da2 As New OleDbDataAdapter(query2, con)
da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha",fecha)
Dim DT2 As New DataTable
da2.Fill(DT2)
```

**Edit:**

En uno de tus comentarios dices lo siguiente:

> En la base de datos ese campo está con datos como 27/04/2017 08:30 mientras que yo lo comparo con 27/04/2017

En ese caso, no puedes usar el comparador `=` en tu consulta. Yo te recomiendo usar `BETWEEN` y usar dos fechas: la quieres y la del dia siguiente, algo asi:

```
Dim fecha As Date = DateSerial(TBAnio.Text, TBMes.Text, TBDia.Text)
Dim fecha2 As Date = fecha.AddDays(1)
Dim query2 As String = "SELECT CheckTime, CheckType FROM Checkinout WHERE CheckTime BETWEEN @fecha and @fecha2"
da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha",fecha)
da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha2",fecha2)
...
```

Comment: Sigue sin aparecer nada, la conexión con la BD está bien ya que saco otros datos, por lo que es a la hora de compararlo con `fecha`. En la base de datos ese campo está con datos como `27/04/2017 08:30` mientras que yo lo comparo con `27/04/2017` por ello he probado poniendo `*` o `%` con el sentido de `fecha` seguido de cualquier cosa, no se si me explico, pero no lo he conseguido

Comment: @CharlieMR porque en ese caso, debes usar el comparador > o between: `SELECT CheckTime, CheckType FROM Checkinout WHERE CheckTime > @fecha"` o `SELECT CheckTime, CheckType FROM Checkinout WHERE CheckTime between @fecha and @fecha2"`

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que no estas pasando bien la fecha a la consulta.

Para que el motor de la DB pille bien la fecha que le estas pasando para compararla con una columna puedes añadirla como una string de la siguiente forma:

```
Dim query2 As String = "SELECT CheckTime, CheckType FROM Checkinout WHERE CheckTime = '" & fecha.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "'"
```

Al pasar cualquier dato como `string` en una query SQL debes siempre añadir las comillas simple `'` para identificarlo como `string`.

También puedes pasarlo por parámetros indicando el tipo de dato que le pasas:

```
Dim query2 As String = "SELECT CheckTime, CheckType FROM Checkinout WHERE CheckTime = @fecha"
Dim COMANDO As New OleDbCommand(query2, con);
COMANDO.Parameters.Add("@fecha", OleDbType.Date).Value = fecha;
Dim DA2 As New OleDbDataAdapter(COMANDO)
Dim DT2 As New DataTable
DA2.Fill(DT2)
```

Comment: salta error ahora en `DA2.Fill(DT2)` : 'No coinciden los tipos de datos en la expresión de criterios.', ¿Por qué puede ser?

Comment: @CharlieMR He editado la pregunta añadiendo una opción mejor, hacerlo por parámetros. Prueba eso a ver si soluciona el problema.

Comment: Sigue sin aparecer nada, la conexión con la BD está bien ya que saco otros datos, por lo que es a la hora de compararlo con `fecha`. En la base de datos ese campo está con datos como `27/04/2017 08:30` mientras que yo lo comparo con `27/04/2017` por ello he probado poniendo `*` o `%` con el sentido de `fecha` seguido de cualquier cosa, no se si me explico, pero no lo he conseguido

Comment: Las fechas en access van entre #